# not able to copy after login to remote server

Tags: cp, remote, recursive

Below is my code to copy one folder from one path to another path after login to remote server. Problem I am facing, once after login to remote server I am not able to copy the source directory to destination directory.

---

```
echo "PLEASE ENTER LIB NAME "
read dirname
echo "You entered: $dirname"


echo "PLEASE ENTER VERSION"
echo "example 1.0   etc"
read version

NOW=$(date +"%Y%m%d")

echo "date $NOW"

##FOR=$(rev<<"$NOW")


echo "PLEASE ENTER EXTENSION"
echo "example 0.0 or 0.1 etc"

read date_extension
echo "You entered: $date_extension"


mkdir "${dirname}@${version}@${NOW}${date_extension}"


TAG_DIR=${dirname}@${version}@${NOW}${date_extension}


mkdir $TAG_DIR/CDSOA

cd $TAG_DIR/

echo `pwd`


echo "PLEASE ENTER SOURCE LIB PATH"
read  path


PATH1=$(cp -Rf $path  `pwd`)
echo "entered path : $PATH1"


read path2
echo "PLEASE ENTER DESTINATION  PATH"
echo $path2



ssh -l prj/ dlhl0654


cp -rf $TAG_DIR  $path2

echo "aaaa"
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you need could be `scp`.

It's `cp` over `ssh`, basically.
It you want to copy a local directory to a remote directory, 
you can use something like

```
scp -r /home/user/localdir remoteuser@remotehost:/tmp/
```

After this, you have a directory on the `remotehost` with the name `localdir`.

See `man scp` - it uses just the same `ssh` connections.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute your remote copy commands within the `ssh` shell. I'm guessing prj is your username to login to the remote server and dlhl0654 is the remote hostname. Hope you have passwordless authentication setup between the servers. Try this out, it should work.

```
echo "PLEASE ENTER LIB NAME "
read dirname
echo "You entered: $dirname"


echo "PLEASE ENTER VERSION"
echo "example 1.0   etc"
read version

NOW=$(date +"%Y%m%d")

echo "date $NOW"

##FOR=$(rev<<"$NOW")


echo "PLEASE ENTER EXTENSION"
echo "example 0.0 or 0.1 etc"

read date_extension
echo "You entered: $date_extension"


mkdir "${dirname}@${version}@${NOW}${date_extension}"


TAG_DIR=${dirname}@${version}@${NOW}${date_extension}


mkdir $TAG_DIR/CDSOA

cd $TAG_DIR/

echo `pwd`


echo "PLEASE ENTER SOURCE LIB PATH"
read  path


PATH1=$(cp -Rf $path  `pwd`)
echo "entered path : $PATH1"


read path2
echo "PLEASE ENTER DESTINATION  PATH"
echo $path2



ssh -l prj@dlhl0654 <<EOF
cp -rf "$TAG_DIR"  "$path2"
EOF

echo "aaaa"
```